# Specify the memory stride data when storing a buffer via HDF5’s C/C++ API

Tags: c++, numpy, hdf5, stride

I’ve used HDF5 from Python, via `h5py`, quite a bit – I am spoiled by its smooth integration with NumPy. Now, from C/C++-land, I am trying to save and load image data in HDF5 stores, and I am having trouble figuring out how to specify the stride of the image data.

Reading and writing the dimensional data – the matrix shape, in Python – is straightforward; I read it like this:

```cpp
constexpr std::size_t NDIMS = 3;
hid_t space_id = H5Dget_space(dataset_id);
hsize_t dims[NDIMS];
H5Sget_simple_extent_dims(space_id, dims, NULL);
```

… and write it similarly (for an image instance `input`):

```cpp
constexpr std::size_t NDIMS = 3;
hsize_t dims[NDIMS] = { static_cast<hsize_t>(input.dim(0)),
                        static_cast<hsize_t>(input.dim(1)),
                        static_cast<hsize_t>(input.dim(2)) };
/// first arg here is rank (aka NDIMS)
hid_t space_id      = H5Screate_simple(NDIMS, dims, NULL);
```

… the HDF5 code samples I can find are either completely trivial examples – where the data being written or read is very small and of a known size – or extremely advanced and above my current pay-grade, like e.g. the `h5py` or `tables` source. I am looking for a straightforward example of how one maps matrix stride data to the HDF5 API.

Comment: There is no languag C/C++/Objective-C. Each is a language of its own rights. Do not add tags for unrelated languages.

Comment: I'm using the C and C++ APIs, so those were the tags I used. Objective-C is not tagged.

Comment: The code is definitively not C.

Comment: OK, but the functions from the HDF5 API I am using are specifically from the published C API.

Comment: I removed the reference to Objective-C in an edit.